# TrustedInstaller taking 50%

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

This is a Sony Vaio running Vista.

I just did the Windows Update thing (12 updates) and got through the boot to where stuff is "stable".  But when I look at Process Explorer, TrustedInstaller.exe is chewing up 45-50% CPU (it's a dual core).

Comment: you should add that as an answer instead of editing your question :)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I noticed the same thing a few months ago, I found out that after fresh installs(I think updates too) TrustedInstaller goes crazy for some time, and then it stops it's crazyness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, the activity stopped after about 15 minutes and TrustedInstaller.exe no longer appeared in the process list.

My guess is that it was installing some of the updates -- there were updates to MS Office, eg, that likely were good candidates for installing that way.  Had never noticed this behavior before, however.

Comment: Yes, that's Windows Update. And it is normal.